# Быстрый способ создания экземпляра std::vector<std::vector<long>>

Tags: c++, оптимизация, память, vector

У меня есть вектор **std::vectorstd::vector<long>**.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, самый быстрый способ создания экземпляра такого вектора на 1000000 элементов с условием, что внутренние вектора должны быть с зарезервированной памятью на 12 элементов.

Пока использую следующий вариант:

```
std::vector<std::vector<long>> buffer( 1000000, std::vector<long>() );
for( int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
    buffer[ i ].reserve( 12 );
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<long>> buffer(1000000, std::vector<long>(12));` не устраивает?

Comment: Этот вариант будет медленнее чем мой вариант и здесь будет происходить не резервирование памяти, а будут созданы вложенные вектора с количеством элементов 12 и заполнены значениями по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забавные получаются результаты...

Я решил сравнить три варианта - 1. исходный, с резервированием; 2. вариант с векторами с 12 элементами (просто из логики - все равно ведь будут заполняться, иначе зачем резервировать?) и вариант 3. с векторами с 12 элементами с последующей очисткой (потому что хоть этого и нет в стандарте, сброса памяти до 0 обычно не происходит).

```
vector<vector<long>> buffer(1000000, vector<long>(12) );
for( int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i ) buffer[ i ].clear();
```

Полный код и результаты работы можно посмотреть тут - https://ideone.com/98o0Kv

Первый проход без вывода - просто на всякий случай, для сброса кэшей.
Последний вариант - скорее шутки ради: мол, `array` вообще бы не занял времени - может, стоит подумать о его применении?...

Как видим, реально - хотя и не в строгом соответствии со стандартом, да... но в соответствии с практикой - создание сразу 12-элементных векторов быстрее, даже с их последующей очисткой. По крайней мере в GCC. В VC++2019 на моей машине все три варианта оказались практически одинаковы по времени.

Итог: применять ли способ выделения памяти с последующей очисткой - зависит от конкретного компилятора и вашего отношения к легкому нестандарту...

Comment: Спасибо за проделанную работу. Буду думать над тем каким способом пользоваться.